# MySQL Trigger STR_TO_DATE(NEW.invoice_date, '%d/%m/%Y')

Tags: mysql, sql, date, triggers, format

I am trying to make a MySQL trigger before insert:

```
BEGIN
    SET NEW.order_date = STR_TO_DATE(NEW.order_date, '%d/%m/%Y');
END
```

But when I import the .csv containing records like  "05/07/2017" the trigger imports only NULL

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: At the point of triggering this, `order_date` has already been coerced to a `date`. It is no longer in its initial string form.

Comment: So if I change column order_date to VarChar and create new column for example order_date_fixed which is in format DATE and the Trigger is changed to:

BEGIN
    SET NEW.order_date = STR_TO_DATE(NEW.order_date_fixed, '%d/%m/%Y');
END

Would it work as it is supposed to?

Comment: Just omit the conversion in your trigger.

Comment: @FinrodFElagund You have the fields the wrong way round. As you've described it, you'd actually need to do `SET NEW.order_date_fixed = STR_TO_DATE(NEW.order_date, '%d/%m/%Y')`. Not that this is a great solution, as it can lead to issues where one of the dates gets updated later but not the other and you end up with potential logical issues. I much prefer the option of fixing the CSV file before import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On searching, this appears to be a question that has been asked a few times in various places but I can find little in the way of explanation of the cause.

As I have mentioned in my comment above, the trigger is too late in the process to transform the data appropriately.

In order to have *triggered* the trigger, the data has to have been converted to the appropriate data types for inserting into the table.

As such, when passing the data to `str_to_date()`, you only have the coerced `date` field available, not the initial string.

Two ways are available to fix this:

1. Fix the date format in the file before importing
2. Use a temporary `varchar` field to import and then use a trigger to transform this to a `date` field